# Rushed passport - does my reason qualify?

Tags: passports, international-travel, canadian-citizens

I was gifted a concert ticket for my birthday & it requires me to travel out of Canada, in a little over two weeks from now, on June 2, 2019. They assumed I had a passport, but I don’t. Can I get a passport rushed for this reason?

Only concert tickets were bought, not airline tickets. Help!!

Comment: Do you have to travel by air? If you're going to the US you can enter overland on an enhanced driving licence or enhanced ID card.

Comment: May 15 has already passed. You would not be able to attend anything on that date without a time machine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Seems to me that May 15/19 is just quantifying _now_ and that intended date of travel is 2 weeks from this date.

Comment: I would be flying out June 2****

Comment: I am flying overseas

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are a Canadian citizen, [Get urgent, express, weekend and statutory holiday emergency passport service in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/urgent-emergency-passport.html):

> We offer urgent and express passport services at certain locations in Canada. To find out if you can use these services, you must apply in person.
>
> You must provide proof of travel for urgent service. You may also need to provide it for express service.
>
> Proof of travel can be:
>
> •  an airline, bus or train ticket
>
> • a written declaration, if travelling by car
>
> • a travel itinerary showing travel proof of payment
>
> •    proof of illness or death in the family requiring immediate travel
>
> Depending on the reason for your travel, you may need to show further proof that your situation is urgent.
>
> We won’t be liable for any losses if we can’t deliver the passport in time for travel to you or your child. We recommend that you don’t finalize any travel plans until you get your passport.

If you're traveling by car, it looks like they'll accept a declaration stating your intent to do so. They're not really concerned with why you want to travel, just some proof that your travel is imminent. But the proof is only strictly required for urgent service (1-2 business days) and may not be needed for express service (2-9 business days).

Answer (score 8):

You probably do not need to provide a reason, just proof of upcoming travel. According to [Get urgent, express, weekend and statutory holiday emergency passport service in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/urgent-emergency-passport.html):

> **You must provide proof of travel for urgent service.** You may also need to provide it for express service.

The "express pick-up" fee is CAN$50 and the processing time is 2-9 business days, which will be just enough if you're applying today.

The "urgent pick-up" service is next day and you may need to provide an acceptable reason for your urgent travel.